# How can I show/hide FloatingActionButton when scrolling RecyclerView using Behavior when RecyclerView is inside SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

How can I show/hide `FloatingActionButton` when scrolling `RecyclerView` using `Behavior` when `RecyclerView` is inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`? I'm using 22.2.0 version of Support Design Library.

I'm attaching my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_padding_top"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using outdated version of Support Design Library. Updating it to version 23.2.0 solved my problem.

Custom FAB `Behavior` (from article [How to hide/show Toolbar when list is scrolling (part 3)](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/)):

```
public class ScrollingFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    private int toolbarHeight;

    public ScrollingFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
        this.toolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, fab, dependency) || (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
        boolean returnValue = super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, fab, dependency);
        if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
                int fabBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
                int distanceToScroll = fab.getHeight() + fabBottomMargin;
                float ratio = (float)dependency.getY()/(float)toolbarHeight;
                fab.setTranslationY(-distanceToScroll * ratio);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_outline_white_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="...ScrollingFABBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```